# Remove element from list based on condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list `l`:

```
l = [0.22, 0.6, 0.94, 1.28, 1.66, 2., 2.38, 2.72, 3.04, 3.42, 3.76, 4.2, 4.58, 4.94, 5.32, 5.68, 6.08, 6.42, 6.8, 7.22, 7.54]
```

I want to remove from the list all elements which are within a 1.00 distance to the previous element. This involves of course to stay at element i if element i+1 has been removed and check the difference between element i and element i+2 and so on. The desired output would be:

```
output = [0.22, 1.28, 2.38, 3.42, 4.58, 5.68, 6.8]
```

I obviously tried to do this with a for-loop but as this failed, I remembered that Python does not allow altering a list within a loop.

```
for index, i in enumerate(l[:-1]):
    j = l[index+1]
    if (j-i) < 1:
        p.remove(j)
    else:
        continue
```

Furthermore, I know that `itertools` contains the `pairwise` method for `Python 3.10` and above, which makes it possible to calculate differences (which might be useful for this task) but I am using `3.7.6`.
Any solution is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The pairwise recipe will work fine in 3.7.6 (although I don't think it solves your problem here...)

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Please show us your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: @JonClements If I import pairwise from itertools I get an error: cannot import name 'pairwise' from 'itertools' (unknown location)

Comment: @buhtz I edited my post adding my try. However, magimix's answer below works fine.

Comment: @lonyen11 what I meant was, was the "recipe" works fine... eg: if you copied the code in the "Roughly equivalent to" example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
l = [0.22, 0.6, 0.94, 1.28, 1.66, 2., 2.38, 2.72, 3.04, 3.42, 3.76, 4.2, 4.58, 
4.94, 5.32, 5.68, 6.08, 6.42, 6.8, 7.22, 7.54]
l2 = [l[0]]

for elm in l:
    if abs(elm - l2[-1]) > 1:
        l2.append(elm)

print(l2)
```